# Wordpress backend is slow - MySQL analysis

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress backend being slow. Sometimes it takes ~ 20 seconds when I see the page.

I have followed these steps. I updated WP 5.7.3 → 5.8.1. I have updated the add-ons:

```
Classic Editor
Contact Form 7
Disable Comments
Elementor
Gallery Custom Links
Loco Translate
NextGEN Gallery
Redux
Yoast SEO
```

Suddenly the back office started to work quickly. I made a backup (files and MySQL) using rsync. I was happy until I clicked on the "plugins" tab. Then the speed returned to its original state. She slowed down. I backed up again (files and MySQL) and compared both copies (fast and slow). There are no changes in the files.

I did a diff comparison of both databases.

I assume that the base is responsible for the slowing down of the WordPress backend. Summary of differences (lack of description is, in my opinion, of little importance)

```
618c618
627,628c627,628 wpp_options
630c630 wpp_options elementor_log
1300c1300
3108c3108
3117c3117 wpp_usermeta
3237c3237 wpp_wfconfig
3350c3350
3359c3359 wpp_wfhits
3527c3527
3536c3536 wpp_wflogins
4206c4206
```

The results of the differences are listed under the link → http://tomaszroot.usermd.net/base.txt

What can happen if I click on the "plugins" tab, who can help me?

Comment: This question is really off topic, however let me say that in some cases when your admin is doing remote API calls to check for updates, it can take a while, depending on which repos they are checking. This is more often (in my experience) true for non WordPress hosted plugins.

Comment: Next troubleshooting step:  Install John Blackbourn's [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin, and see if it tells you where your problems lie.  Also, if you're using Redis or memcached Object Caches, flush (empty out) those caches.

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/